Unable to connect to Redis | Spring Boot
I've a redis service on upstash.io but not able to connect to it from my spring boot application
This is my redis config
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("myhost");
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("password")); // Uncomment if password is needed
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

     @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }

} 

This is my redis service
@Component 
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
public class RedisService { 
    
    @Autowired
    private final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate; 
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void testConnection() {
        try {
            redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().ping();
            System.out.println("Connected to Redis successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to Redis: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 
    public <V> void set(String key, V value, long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) { 
        System.out.println("Storing message to redis cache: Key[" + key + "]");
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value); 
        redisTemplate.expire(key, timeout, timeUnit); 
    } 

    public <V> V get(String key) { 
        return (V) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key); 
    } 
 
    public Boolean hasKey(String key) { 
        return redisTemplate.hasKey(key); 
    } 
} 

This is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springprojects</groupId>
    <artifactId>realtimechatapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>realtimechatapp</name>
    <description>Chat Application using Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId> 
        </dependency> 

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>


Logs:
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Connection closed prematurely
I've tried to increas the timeout but did not work.
Connecting with redis on local also give same error
redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("localhost");
redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
Updated Redis config
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        System.out.println("Creating RedisConnectionFactory");
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        System.out.println("Creating RedisTemplate");
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }
}



it's better to leverage spring boot auto configuration feature. I have used similar in my case as well.
Add below properties in application.properties file.
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
#spring.redis.password=Redis@2024 //if required
#spring.cache.type=redis
spring.cache.redis.cache-null-values=true
#spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=40000

Add @EnableCaching in main class. I think using these two condition it will auto configure then you can use associated classes of redis.

I've used your approach but it is still not working. (added Updated Redis config file in the question above) Also used @EnableCaching on my main spring boot class.

You say you're wanting to use an upstash redis instance, but your code refers to myhost and 3679.
If you replace those with the upstash endpoint's domain name (which would be long and rather randomized) and port (which would default to other than 6379), as well as that endpoint's redis password, does it work then?

I can't expose my redis upstash details publicly, that's why i've written myhost in its place. My app is not able to connect to both local and upstash redis

For me, this worked:
LettucePoolingClientConfiguration lettuceConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().build();
return new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterProperties.getStandaloneConfiguration(), lettuceConfig);

The lettuce config decides if SSL is used:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/c1521b610e8be0d8fa748fac673a33b15190704f/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceConnectionFactory.java#L1456
It took a little digging to get this. I hope this helps other people.
